# Set minimum height or width for column Apexcharts chart

Tags: charts, apexcharts

If data is very lower than others, it's almost like zero, and the user can't click because it's too small.

How can I set a minimum height or width for small numbers?

[Gif](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20030910/82160556-73ed9100-98ab-11ea-82e9-8b8e0725212f.gif)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function when chart render end

```js
function svgBalancer(minHeight, absUnit, bool) {
  let cols = document.getElementsByClassName("apexcharts-bar-area");
  let labels = document.getElementsByClassName("apexcharts-datalabel");
  for (let i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    if (parseFloat(cols[i].getAttribute("barHeight")) <= minHeight && parseFloat(cols[i].getAttribute("barHeight")) != 0) {
      let d = cols[i].getAttribute("d");
      d = d.split(" ");
      if (bool == false) {
        let d2 = d[2].split(".");
        d2[0] = absUnit;
        d[2] = d2.join(".");
        let d3 = d[3].split(".");
        d3[0] = absUnit;
        d[3] = d3.join(".");
      } else {
        let d4 = d[4].split(".");
        d4[0] = absUnit;
        d[4] = d4.join(".");
        let d6 = d[6].split(".");
        d6[0] = absUnit;
        d[6] = d6.join(".");
      }
      cols[i].setAttribute("d", d.join(" "));
      let yLabel = parseFloat(labels[i].getAttribute("y"));
      let delta = yLabel - absUnit;
      yLabel = yLabel - delta - 8;
      labels[i].setAttribute("y", yLabel);
    }
  }
}

updated: function(chartContext, config) {
    svgBalancer(8, 313, true);
},
animationEnd: function(chartContext, options) {
    svgBalancer(8, 313, false);
}
```

The code does not work well but it is better than nothing.

[image]

[image]